# Unable to check if field exists on MongoDB using NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using NodeJs and MongoDb as a backend service from my android app.I am checking if Phone field exists in my database.
My problem is everytime I check for the field it sends response field exists even if Phone field is not present in document.

Here is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const env = require('dotenv').config();
const router = express.Router();
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var dburl = process.env.URL;

router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

router.post('/checkPhone',(req,res) => {

        var data = req.body.uId;

MongoClient.connect(dburl,{useNewUrlParser:true},(err,client) => {

              if(err){

                console.log("Error:" +err);
              }
              else{

                var collect = client.db('Bookbudi_db').collection('Users');

                collect.find({_id:data,Phone:{$exists:true}},(err,doc) => {

                             if(err){

                                console.log("Error:" +err);
                             }
                             if(doc){

                                res.send("Exist");
                             }
                             else{

                                res.send("Doesn't exist");
                             }

                });

              }

     });  

 });

module.exports = router;
```

Someone please let me know what I am doing wrong in above code. Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: could you please tell me what are you getting if you "console.log(doc)"

Comment: can you please use this command once. collect.find({_id:data,Phone:{"$exists":true}, $ne: null } })

Comment: could you please use apostrophies("") for _id & Phone & check once?

Comment: @PALLAMOLLASAI, On doing console.log(doc) its is returning cursor having various things.

Comment: Finally I got the fix actually I replace find() with findOne().

Answer (score 0):

if `{ $exists:true }` returns the document - it means that the field is there.

It is possible that your schema defines this field and initiates it w/ `null` - note that `$exists` will still return those fields.

References:
[$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#op._S_exists)

Comment: But I have 3 documents in database and Phone field is present in only one document out of three.

Comment: are you 100% sure?

Comment: can you try the query w/ `{$exists:false}` and post what it returns?

Comment: I have tried it also but still returning Exists.In both cases it is returning if(doc) condition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194010/discussion-between-aviad-and-digvijay).